# What is the meaning of the word I am asking about

Tags: одним-словом

My question is probably off-topic but hope I can get an answer here. There is a game which is played in russia and to make the player feel the russian atmosphere the english narration contains russian words. There is a scene in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=OgEHQg2Y8wg) video at 1:15 where the following paragraph could be heard.

> Ulman enough of jokes! ***[Russian word here]*** When we are back at the base you will be sweeping tunnels with a toothbrush!

My question, what russian word is that, and what is it's meaning?

Comment: [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/блин](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Answer (score 3):

It's the word "блин". While it's primarty meening is ["a pankake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blini), though, this russian thing is a lot thinner thank actual american pankakes, as I understand it.

In slang it is used with a meaning of "damn" or similar. In this case the word is an euphemism of "блядь" (blyad, "a whore"), part of russian filthy language, the latter can't be used openly in some cases, for example, in mass media, so euphemisms go.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's «блин» — slang word, smth like «geez», «damn».